# Filter comma separated span text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-filter

I am using the jQuery `.filter()` function to check whether or not a particular value is selected in a checkbox list:

```
$("#Control").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
             .next("label")
             .filter(function () {
                return $.trim($(this).text()) == "Option 1"; 
             })
             .length != 0';
```

How can I accomplish this if I have a comma-separated list of values in a span and I want to check if a particular value is there or not?

ex. `Home Phone, Email Address, Mobile Phone` might be the span text

Comment: You want to check that, in a comma-separated string of values, from a `span` that a particular string is in that span? So checking for 'foo' from the text `foo, bar, baz`?

Comment: yes but only by filter method

Comment: Why do you need to complicate it using `filter()`, `indexOf()` would be more than enough to do this, and rather less expensive to run. Oh, and give an example of what sort of `span` text you expect to have and what sort of values you'll be looking for.

Comment: it's system requirement that's why have to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the text of the span on `,` and then check to see if your string is inside the resulting array:

```
$("span").filter(function () {
            return $(this).text().split(/,\s*/).indexOf("Email Address") > -1; 
         });
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/nFjCn/3/

Comment: Shouldn't that be `split(/,\s*/)`? It's comma-separated, and I'd expect there to be whitespace following the comma.

Comment: Thanks, the `.` was meant to be `,` He doesn't explicitly state that there is whitespace after the commas. But will add that if he does.

Comment: True, there is a distinct lack of information in the question.

Comment: @RichardDalton my span is not in $("#Control") i will make this simple i have just a span and text like this Home Phone, Email Address, Mobile Phone now i have to filter that it has value Email Address there or not

Comment: @rahul Updated my answer to reflect the additional information

Answer (score 2):

Why not this ? With Regex, but I think there's other easier solutions.

```
$("#Control").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked")
             .next("label")
             .filter(function () {
                 var regex = /,? *Email Address *,?/;
                 return regex.test($(this).text()); 
             }).length != 0;
```

Same example than @Richard Dalton here http://jsfiddle.net/nFjCn/1/
You have to make sure a white space follows your text in the regex.